# element hidden behind other elements

Tags: html, css

i'm not even sure why this is happening, Its a Css error but im not sure where

I'm doing this in rails so im relatively new to this but it should be standard css!

[image: What the problem is]

As you can see the element  "ticket" is hidden behind the cards (not sure why), I'm wanting the ticket above the images so it can be editable!

Here is the code

**Css**

```
// Place all the styles related to the view controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
.box{
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 125px);
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - 125px);
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 300px);
}

.ticket{
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #FFB300;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px #aaa;
  border-top: 1px solid #E89F3D;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E89F3D;
}

.left{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
}

.left li{
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

.left li:nth-child(-n+2){
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #FFB300;
}

.left li:nth-child(3),
.left li:nth-child(6){
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #EEEEEE;
}

.left li:nth-child(4){
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #EEEEEE;
}

.left li:nth-child(5){
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid #EEEEEE;
}

.left li:nth-child(7),
.left li:nth-child(9),
.left li:nth-child(11),
.left li:nth-child(12){
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.left li:nth-child(8){
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.left li:nth-child(10){
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.left li:nth-child(13){
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #FFB300;
}

.left li:nth-child(14){
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #FFB300;
}

.right{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -5px;
}

.right li:nth-child(-n+2){
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #FFB300;
}

.right li:nth-child(3),
.right li:nth-child(4),
.right li:nth-child(6){
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #EEEEEE;
}

.right li:nth-child(5){
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #EEEEEE;
}

.right li:nth-child(8),
.right li:nth-child(9),
.right li:nth-child(11){
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.right li:nth-child(7){
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.right li:nth-child(10){
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.right li:nth-child(12){
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.right li:nth-child(13),
.right li:nth-child(14){
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #FFB300;
}

.ticket:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 250px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset 0 -10px 0 #B56E0A,
    inset 0 -20px 0 #FFB300,
    inset 0 -30px 0 #B56E0A,
    inset 0 -40px 0 #FFB300,
    inset 0 -50px 0 #999999,
    inset 0 -60px 0 #E5E5E5,
    inset 0 -70px 0 #999999,
    inset 0 -80px 0 #E5E5E5,
    inset 0 -90px 0 #999999,
    inset 0 -100px 0 #E5E5E5,
    inset 0 -110px 0 #999999,
    inset 0 -120px 0 #E5E5E5,
    inset 0 -130px 0 #999999,
    inset 0 -140px 0 #E5E5E5,
    inset 0 -150px 0 #B0B0B0,
    inset 0 -160px 0 #EEEEEE,
    inset 0 -170px 0 #B0B0B0,
    inset 0 -180px 0 #EEEEEE,
    inset 0 -190px 0 #B0B0B0,
    inset 0 -200px 0 #EEEEEE,
    inset 0 -210px 0 #B0B0B0,
    inset 0 -220px 0 #FFB300,
    inset 0 -230px 0 #B56E0A,
    inset 0 -240px 0 #FFB300,
    inset 0 -250px 0 #B56E0A;
}

.ticket:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  right: 199px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 250px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset 0 -10px 0 #F4D483,
    inset 0 -20px 0 #FFB300,
    inset 0 -30px 0 #F4D483,
    inset 0 -40px 0 #FFB300,
    inset 0 -50px 0 #FFFFFF,
    inset 0 -60px 0 #E5E5E5,
    inset 0 -70px 0 #FFFFFF,
    inset 0 -80px 0 #E5E5E5,
    inset 0 -90px 0 #FFFFFF,
    inset 0 -100px 0 #E5E5E5,
    inset 0 -110px 0 #FFFFFF,
    inset 0 -120px 0 #E5E5E5,
    inset 0 -130px 0 #FFFFFF,
    inset 0 -140px 0 #E5E5E5,
    inset 0 -150px 0 #FFFFFF,
    inset 0 -160px 0 #EEEEEE,
    inset 0 -170px 0 #FFFFFF,
    inset 0 -180px 0 #EEEEEE,
    inset 0 -190px 0 #FFFFFF,
    inset 0 -200px 0 #EEEEEE,
    inset 0 -210px 0 #FFFFFF,
    inset 0 -220px 0 #FFB300,
    inset 0 -230px 0 #F4D483,
    inset 0 -240px 0 #FFB300,
    inset 0 -250px 0 #F4D483;
}

.content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  background: #eee;
}

.airline{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(0,0,102,1);
}

.boarding{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 220px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

.jfk{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #222;
}

.sfo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 180px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #222;
}

.plane{
  position: absolute;
  left: 105px;
  top: 0px;
}

.sub-content{
  background: #e5e5e5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
}

.watermark{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: -10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 110px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.name{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
}

.name span{
  color: #555;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.flight{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 180px;
  font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
}

.flight span{
  color: #555;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.gate{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 280px;
  font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
}

.gate span{
  color: #555;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.seat{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 350px;
  font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
}

.seat span{
  color: #555;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.boardingtime{
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 10px;
  font-family: Arial Narrow, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
}

.boardingtime span{
  color: #555;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.barcode{
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  bottom: 6px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  background: #222;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #FFB300, inset -2px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -4px 0 0 #222,
    inset -5px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -6px 0 0 #222,
    inset -9px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -12px 0 0 #222,
    inset -13px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -14px 0 0 #222,
    inset -15px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -16px 0 0 #222,
    inset -17px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -19px 0 0 #222,
    inset -20px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -23px 0 0 #222,
    inset -25px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -26px 0 0 #222,
    inset -26px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -27px 0 0 #222,
    inset -30px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -31px 0 0 #222,
    inset -33px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -35px 0 0 #222,
    inset -37px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -40px 0 0 #222,
    inset -43px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -44px 0 0 #222,
    inset -45px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -46px 0 0 #222,
    inset -48px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -49px 0 0 #222,
    inset -50px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -52px 0 0 #222,
    inset -54px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -55px 0 0 #222,
    inset -57px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -59px 0 0 #222,
    inset -61px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -64px 0 0 #222,
    inset -66px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -67px 0 0 #222,
    inset -68px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -69px 0 0 #222,
    inset -71px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -72px 0 0 #222,
    inset -73px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -75px 0 0 #222,
    inset -77px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -80px 0 0 #222,
    inset -82px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -83px 0 0 #222,
    inset -84px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -86px 0 0 #222,
    inset -88px 0 0 #FFB300,
    inset -89px 0 0 #222,
    inset -90px 0 0 #FFB300;
}

.slip{
  left: 455px;
}

.nameslip{
  top: 60px;
  left: 410px;
}

.flightslip{
  left: 410px;
}

.seatslip{
  left: 540px;
}

.jfkslip{
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 410px;
}

.sfoslip{
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 530px;
}

.planeslip{
  top: 10px;
  left: 475px;
}

.airlineslip{
  left: 455px;
}
```

**Html**

```
<% title("Home Page") %>
<h1><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home Page <small>views/pages/home.html.erb</small></h1>
<div class="section" style="background-image: url('https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1334/1484360775_8391c2ce1a_b.jpg')">
<div class="container" style="color: white">
  <div class="box">
    <ul class="left">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="right">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="ticket">
      <span class="airline">Lufthansa</span>
      <span class="airline airlineslip">Lufthansa</span>
      <span class="boarding">Boarding pass</span>
      <div class="content">
        <span class="jfk">JFK</span>
        <span class="plane"><?xml version="1.0" ?><svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" height="60" width="60" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g stroke="#222"><line fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="30" x1="300" x2="55" y1="390" y2="390"/><path d="M98 325c-9 10 10 16 25 6l311-156c24-17 35-25 42-50 2-15-46-11-78-7-15 1-34 10-42 16l-56 35 1-1-169-31c-14-3-24-5-37-1-10 5-18 10-27 18l122 72c4 3 5 7 1 9l-44 27-75-15c-10-2-18-4-28 0-8 4-14 9-20 15l74 63z" fill="#222" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="10"/></g></svg></span>
        <span class="sfo">SFO</span>

        <span class="jfk jfkslip">JFK</span>
        <span class="plane planeslip"><?xml version="1.0" ?><svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" height="50" width="50" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g stroke="#222"><line fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="30" x1="300" x2="55" y1="390" y2="390"/><path d="M98 325c-9 10 10 16 25 6l311-156c24-17 35-25 42-50 2-15-46-11-78-7-15 1-34 10-42 16l-56 35 1-1-169-31c-14-3-24-5-37-1-10 5-18 10-27 18l122 72c4 3 5 7 1 9l-44 27-75-15c-10-2-18-4-28 0-8 4-14 9-20 15l74 63z" fill="#222" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="10"/></g></svg></span>
        <span class="sfo sfoslip">SFO</span>
        <div class="sub-content">
          <span class="watermark">Lufthansa</span>
          <span class="name">PASSENGER NAME<br><span>Rex, Anonasaurus</span></span>
          <span class="flight">FLIGHT N&deg;<br><span>X3-65C3</span></span>
          <span class="gate">GATE<br><span>11B</span></span>
          <span class="seat">SEAT<br><span>45A</span></span>
          <span class="boardingtime">BOARDING TIME<br><span>8:25PM ON AUGUST 2013</span></span>

           <span class="flight flightslip">FLIGHT N&deg;<br><span>X3-65C3</span></span>
            <span class="seat seatslip">SEAT<br><span>45A</span></span>
           <span class="name nameslip">PASSENGER NAME<br><span>Rex, Anonasaurus</span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="barcode"></div>
      <div class="barcode slip"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://admitme.co.uk/img/Artisit%20Images/CalvinHarris.jpg">
            <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
            I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://admitme.co.uk/img/Artisit%20Images/CalvinHarris.jpg">
            <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
            I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://admitme.co.uk/img/Artisit%20Images/CalvinHarris.jpg">
            <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
            I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/036d1hcu/)

Comment: Where is the code for the cards?

Comment: Sorry i'll add that all in now!

Comment: Better if you create a JSFiddle with all your codes.

Comment: @Shehary Could you expand?

Comment: @Tester123 I can expand, how much you want me too :P

Comment: Here is a fiddle, anyone wants to play with it http://jsfiddle.net/036d1hcu/

Comment: @Shehary the fiddle is pointless because they didn't include all of the code for their cards.

Comment: @Alejalapeno aaaaaaaaaahhhhhhaaaaaaaaaannnn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cards are in a `.row` div following the ticket. Elements further down in the DOM have a higher z position than the elements above them in the DOM and appear "in front" of them. To alter the normal hierarchy use the `z-index` property.

```
.row {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You could also reverse the hierarchy of your HTML so that the ticket is after the `.row`. This would work because your natural hierarchy now places the ticket above `.row`.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, I looked at removing the row class to which nothing happened

Comment: If i add it to the bottom of the page it appears on top, Which is great, Except i want it as a header so above the cards not on top!

Comment: You NEED to clarify your language. If by ABOVE the cards you mean the ticket is displayed and then as if on a new line the cards appear that's entirely different. Remove `position: absolute` from `.box`. Absolute elements don't exist in the flow. And if you still want to position it use `position: relative`

Answer (score -1):

To force the ticket element to go to bottom of the previous element (new line) , try adding to .ticket css:

display: list-item;

Comment: This didnt do anything, I need it showing rather than hiding behind the cards

Comment: so you want contents of row div below the ticket ?
.row { display: list-item; } ?